# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object [QUICKBLOX DIALOG]

Tags: android, serialization, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am facing an issue in quickblox since 15th April, when Quickblox updated SDK for android to 2.5.2.
The problem that i noticed is like, if i have **customData** parameter filled for a dialog, then it throws the IOExeption mentioned below. else no issues.

*Dialog that casues no issues.*

> QBDialog{id=xxxx, created_at=2016-19-04 11:36:54,
>   last_msg_user_id=xxxx, occupants_ids=[xxxx, xxxx, last_message=hey,
>   last_message_date_sent=1461046124, type=PRIVATE, name=xxxx,
>   room_jid=null, user_id=xxxx, photo=null, unread_message_count=0,
>   customData=null}

*Dialog that causes Crash.*

> QBDialog{id=xxxx, created_at=2016-19-04 12:01:00,
>   last_msg_user_id=xxxx, occupants_ids=[xxxx, xxxx], last_message=hello,
>   last_message_date_sent=1461047494, type=PRIVATE, name=xxxx,
>   room_jid=null, user_id=xxxx, photo=null, unread_message_count=1,
>   customData=QBBaseCustomObject{className='DialogueRelationState',
>   fields={isFriends=true, location_field=null}}}

**Code segment that passes dialogs like above to Activity_chat class**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.getString(selectedDialog.toString());
bundle.putSerializable(Activity_Chat.EXTRA_DIALOG, selectedDialog);
Activity_Chat.start(DrawActivity_Chatlist.this, bundle);// error points here
```

**start method of the receiving Activity**

```
public static void start(Context context, Bundle bundle) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity_Chat.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    context.startActivity(intent); //error points here
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.quickblox.chat.model.QBDialog)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1323)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1271)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
       at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643)
       at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7152)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2663)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3458)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3780)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3748)
       at com.social.fitspur.activities.Activity_Chat.start(Activity_Chat.java:100)
       at com.social.fitspur.activities.DrawActivity_Chatlist$3.onItemClick(DrawActivity_Chatlist.java:198)
       at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1162)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2953)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3708)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject$1
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1366)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
       at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:995)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1055)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1406)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:981)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1076)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1406)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:981)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1076)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1406)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1318)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1271)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
       at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643)
       at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7152)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2663)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3458)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3780)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3748)
       at com.social.fitspur.activities.Activity_Chat.start(Activity_Chat.java:100)
       at com.social.fitspur.activities.DrawActivity_Chatlist$3.onItemClick(DrawActivity_Chatlist.java:198)
       at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1162)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2953)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3708)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

what i understand from this is, it encounters something as JSON in the Dialog which is not serializable and hence the error.

**NOTE: This was working fine before April 15th, and i have not made any changes to my custom class too**

I have tried upgrading SDK version from v2.5 to v2.5.2, but no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickBlox recently added a location_field which was returning a jsonObject but was expecting string. Finally adding this lines while getting dialogs made the trick.

```
for (QBDialog dialog : dialogs) {
    QBDialogCustomData customData = dialog.getCustomData();
    usersIDs.addAll(dialog.getOccupants());
    if (customData == null) {
        continue;
    }
    HashMap<String, Object> fields = customData.getFields();
    if (!fields.isEmpty()) {
        fields.put("location_field", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same exception, but I don't know where can I add the previous code, the issue happen with me when I try to create new dialog.

Comment: Which previous code u r talking about? This above problem will arise only if you are adding custom data to the dialog. Otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

My solution was exlude simple date format:

```
 public static void setGroupDialog(QBDialog qbDialog) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return f.getName().equals("sdf");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    String json = builder.create().toJson(qbDialog);
    getAuthPreferences(YOUR_APP_CONTEXT).edit()
            .putString(PREF_GROUP_DIALOG, json).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Instead now my whole project is effected by this issue. So for the time being I am using this technique which is not good but we can use and latter when they update SDK we can revert our changes in seconds. My all classes which are dependent on QBDialog they are crashing now. So now I am sharing with you one of my class code block. Which may be help full for you.

Crash code:

```
public class ChattingActivity extends ... {


    public static final void start(Context context, QBDialog qbDialog)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,ChattingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, qbDialog); 
            context.startActivity(intent); // Crash when try to start
    }
}
```

Stable code:

```
public class ChattingActivity extends ... {

    private static QBDialog QB_DIALOG;

    public static final void start(Context context, QBDialog qbDialog)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,ChattingActivity.class);
        //  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, qbDialog);
            ChattingActivity.QB_DIALOG = qbDialog;
            context.startActivity(intent); // Crash when try to start
    }

    // Important: Should do null in OnDestroy.
        @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      QB_DIALOG = null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Ok, Thanx for the response.. I had decompiled their jar file and found the issue for which i then wrote a small piece of code. In my case i found that quickblox had added new field for location in their CustomData class but the same was not updated in the sdk.

Comment: its 2019 , I'm still facing that issue

Comment: @ImranSamed Can you ask directly Quickblox. I remember they fixed the issue but I am not working on their SDK from a long time. So I am not able to help you.